# How to simplify an if-else statement matching IP address

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, rhel

I have the following If-Else statement which I  want to simplify.

```bash
if [[ "$IP" == 192.* ]] || [[ "$IPAddr" == 193.* ]]
then
    data="correct data set"
fi
```

I need to include more of `[[ "$IP" == 192.* ]]` and want to see if there is better way to do the same rather than using too many `||` statements

Comment: Be careful... `192.*` matches `192.168.*.*`, and that is a private IP address. `192.200.*.*`, `193.*` and `194.*` are *not* private IP addresses.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it more easily with `case`.

```
case "$IP" in 
    192.* | 193.*) data="correct data set";;
esac
```

You can add more patterns separated by `|`.

Also, you can use a pattern like `19[23].*` to match both strings.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a glob match, you can use a character range:

```
# 192.0.0.0 or 193.0.0.0
if [[  "$IP" == 19[23].* ]]
then echo "match"; fi
```

Or an extglob alternation:

```
# 192.0.0.0 or 10.0.0.0
if [[  "$IP" == @(192|10).* ]]
then echo "match"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be specifically attempting to match against multiple variables (`$IP`, `$IPAddr`).

If you mean `$IP` in both cases, then the solutions given are good.

Otherwise, each test is a distinct set of A and B comparisons, so a list of `||`'s is likely still going to be your best bet. You *can* format them across lines for maintainability and readability, though...

```
if [[ "$IP"     == 192.* ]] || 
   [[ "$IPAddr" == 193.* ]]
then data="correct data set"
fi
```

`&&` and `||` set up line-spanning context.